# What relative variable to use, to reference the Xcode frameworks path?

Tags: xcode, build-settings

I'm looking to reach this folder, with a relative path:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks

With something like this:

```
$(EXAMPLE)
```

or this:

```
$(EXAMPLE)/Frameworks
```

or this:

```
$(EXAMPLE)/Library/Frameworks
```

Is there such variable available? The [Build Settings Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003931-CH3-SW38) doesn't seem to have one. But I find it odd that it doesn't.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want: `${DEVELOPER_FRAMEWORKS_DIR}`

Here's an example from a compilation run I did a while back (and documented to track such variables):

```
setenv DEVELOPER_FRAMEWORKS_DIR /Users/andy/Applications/Xcode46-DP4.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks
```

(as you can see, this is from Xcode 4.6 DP4, installed in my user `Application` folder).